Por qué los enlaces a documentos pdf en mi web han dejado de abrirse con el visor de pdf de los navegadores?
Hasta ahora cualquier enlace a un .pdf se abría sin problemas y ahora todos los navegadores en cualquier equipo los abren como si fueran texto plano mostrando un galimatías sin sentido, cosas como esto:
******** Inicio *******
0000393359 00000 n 0000406683 00000 n 0000406931 00000 n 0000407114 00000 n 0000407399 00000 n 0000407627 00000 n 0000002476 00000 n trailer <<41202B434340EC44BDDAEB9F18E102C1>]>> startxref 0 %%EOF 114 0 obj<>stream x�b�b`��������� ؀����M�! ���J�Gx}�90:05�2p1�0h0x�r���� �@� ���R�r�t����1��Fr�tBZ�����jl)�"$��*�y�7d3���$�HN�~���qz?[J���D������dK�a!9������!l)?d$'�=H~�8�ǐ-庅��yiEKμ ���!�0٬������7c�t�202��{i& �bV6��`q�'G�B� endstream endobj 7 0 obj<> endobj 8 0 obj<> endobj 9 0 obj<>/ColorSpace<>/Font<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageC/ImageI]/ExtGState<>>> endobj 10 0 obj<>
******** Final *********
Pasa con cualquier pdf, pero todos están bien y son perfectamente accesibles de forma directa, pero no desde la web servida por IIS en un Windows Server 2022.
He comprobado los tipos MIME que parecen correctos y también los encabezados HTTP dónde consta Content-Disposition, Content-Type y X.Powered-By.
Estoy muy desorientado. Agradeceré cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

Prueba con el formato. Quizás tiene algo que ver con un códec

Con el formato de quien? de los pdf? No parece razonable, pasa con cualquier pdf y hasta hace unos dias todos se veian bien. Tiene que ser un problema con IIS. Códecs, dices? Dónde se especifican si es que hay algo similar en IIS. Lo único que to conozco son los tipos MIME i estan bien, en principio o aparentemente.
Acabaré por tener que reinstalar todo el Windows Server, con el php, el MySQL, lod ODBC... un rollo, vamos!
